# Put the links in a list without a html list

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET and my html code gets generated. Now, I want to make my dropdownmenu (which I made with jQuery)to display like a list. As you can see  the links are written in a line. What do I have to do to write them among themselves. And I would also like to have the menu dropdown only under the menu where you hover. Anyone know what to do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id$=Submenu]").hide();
  $(".menu_link, .submenu_panel").hover(function() {
    //Hover inn function
    var nthNumber = $(this).index() + 1;
    $("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel").hide();
    $("[id$=Submenu]").show();
    $("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel:nth-of-type(" + nthNumber + ")").show();
  }, function() {
    //Hover out function
    $("[id$=Submenu]").hide();
    var nthNumber = $(this).index() + 1;
    $("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel:nth-of-type(" + nthNumber + ")").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#pnlMenu .menu_link:hover #pnlSubmenu .submenu_link {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
#wrapper_menu {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#menuicon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 27px;
  display: none;
}
.menubar {
  background: #001155;
  height: 4px;
  width: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-top {
  transform: translate(0px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-mid {
  opacity: 0;
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-bottom {
  transform: translate(0px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#menu {
  height: 44px;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95)), color-stop(100%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#c1c0c2', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
#pnlMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu_link {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 13px;
}
.active_menu_link {
  color: #2d98e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)), color-stop(100%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(endColorstr='#c1c0c2', startColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
.last_menu_link {
  float: right;
}
.submenu_link {} .submenu_panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu_link:hover .submenupanel {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper_menu">
  <div id="menuicon">
    <div class="menubar" id="menubar-top"></div>
    <div class="menubar" id="menubar-mid"></div>
    <div class="menubar" id="menubar-bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <nav id="menu">
    <div id="pnlMenu"> <a class="menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=1">menu1</a><a class="menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=2">menu2</a><a class="menu_link active_menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=4">menu3</a><a class="menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=5">menu4</a>
      <a class="menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=6">menu5</a><a href="Index.aspx?category=8">menu6</a>

    </div>
    <div id="pnlSubmenu" style="display:none">
      <div class="submenu_panel" style="height:100px"> <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=7">Link3</a><a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=8">Link4</a>

      </div>
      <div class="submenu_panel" style="height:100px"> <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=4">Link1</a>
        <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=11">Link2</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @raduation I want to connect this https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/19/ with my code, but only the thing that it only dropdown under the exact link and then I want the Link4 under the Link3(I don't really know how, I tried it with the attributes float and with list-style)

Comment: [Check this](http://tinyurl.com/ov7hm57)